# How to load data to a particular section of the page without refreshing the whole page in php-codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3

Sorry if you find this question wrong.
In my website, I have two divs, one div contains the image selected by the user, I have previewed it by Jquery. Then in controller I fetch this image and applied flip operation of Codeigniter, now my question is How to load the second div with flipped image (which will come from controller) without refreshing the whole page? 
[I have three div's, how to load data in only a particular div without reloading the complete page in php-codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181819/i-have-three-divs-how-to-load-data-in-only-a-particular-div-without-reloading)

I know about this link but here data is  coming from database, which is not in my case.
So how to call data in a particular div without loading the whole page?
As I have to upload an image from controller
This is my controller code:

```
$filedata = $this->upload->data();
$data['img2'] = base_url().'/assets/images/'.$filedata['file_name'];  
$this->load->view('pages/flipped',$data);
```

This is view code:

```
<div class="invert-grid-item invert">
<label>Upload Image</label>
<input type='file' name="userfile" size="20">
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="invert-grid-item invert" id="result"></div>
<button id="uploaded_images" type="submit">Invert</button>
```

JS code

```
<script>
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
$('#blah')
.attr('src', e.target.result)
   .width(200)
   .height(200);        };
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
$('#files').on('click',function(){
var files = $('#files')[0].files;
$.ajax({
url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/flip", 
method:"POST",
success:function(data)
{
 $('#uploaded_images').html(data);
 $('#result').val('');
}
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: use jquery and ajax to perform this task.

Comment: How I don't know too much about ajax and jquery can you help?

Comment: you want image to be save in database or just preview into a particular div when you select image from your pc ?

Comment: I have edited the post please check.

Comment: you may go through this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax--net-21684)

Comment: This needs the database connectivity.

Comment: If I'm following this correctly the flow is as follows: user uploads image and you want the same image to be previewed in the same page (without refresh) except you want it flipped? Am I correct? If not describe the flow step by step as if talking to a toddler :)

Comment: I want the flipped image in another div without refreshing the page, the flipping is done in controller

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem, made an ajax call with JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('#upload_form').on('submit', function(e){  
e.preventDefault();  
if($('#userfile').val() == '')  
{  
alert("Please Select the File");  
}  
else  
{  
$.ajax({  
    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/flip",   
    method:"POST",  
    data:new FormData(this),  
    contentType: false,  
    cache: false,  
    processData:false,  
    success:function(data)  
    {  
    $('#result').html(data);
     } 
});  
}  
});
```

});

@ClaudiusDan and @saddam thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer to edited question.

Show the same image with jQuery in another div and look at this question for rotating the second div.

[Rotate a div using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126432/rotate-a-div-using-javascript)

Comment: My data is not coming from database .

Comment: But from where?

Comment: Means I have uploading it to a path in my pc, but I have not done any database connectivity.

Comment: Is there any way to call a flipped image from controller without uploading it to a Path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded 

this may help you

Comment: I have to call an image from controller which is uploaded to a path, Please read my question I have edited

Comment: I have to do that in codeigniter, just tell me how to call controller method in javascript code please ?

Comment: In order to do that you need to call a PHP function with ajax from an external file. If your image is not uploaded on the server, you can not retrieve it from an external file because (at that moment) the image is only on clientside.

Comment: Means it is necessary to upload image to a path when working with codeigniter.